# Equivalent of array join() for Set in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, set

Is there an equivalent of `array join()` for the `Set` class in `Ruby`? or best to just monkey patch my own on the Set class?

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html

Comment: Why not convert the set to an array first? (Do Sets implement `to_a`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What is wrong with `set.to_a.join`?

Something to keep in mind: The documentation says that a *"Set implements a collection of unordered values with no duplicates."* That means the order is not guaranteed. For the `to_a` method the documentation tells you that *"the order of elements is uncertain"*.

I am not sure if a `join` makes sense with this circumstances...

Comment: This worked perfectly, I didn't even think of using to_a! In case of the ordering, this is a pre-processing script used to build a vector for feeding data into a model (random forest and SVM) specifically it will be holding the global dictionary which needs to hold discrete words and order is not a concern. I had previously built it using Arrays but I'm trying to optimise via Benchmark class. Anyway this worked perfectly thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a direct equivalent, as in a method returning a string created by joining the elements of the set with a separator character, but you can use #to_a to convert it to an array and then call #join on that:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-to_a